# Development environment

Tags: php, html, installation, dreamweaver, development-environment

I got kind of a problem, I can't figure out.
I got a local development server set up in my office and an other online dedicated server, to test my web-apps on.
That's all fine as long as I work in my office and use the LAN/WLAN.

But sometimes I'd like to do some quick code changes at home. There's where my problem starts. I tried several possibilities. FTP, VPN, WebDAV, ...
It does work, but the speed is incredibly slow. I need 5 min to chance one or two lines of code.

How's your development environment set up and what option should I use to make the "connection" become faster?

Thank's in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically extreme slow downs like this are due to the IDE you are using. It wants to read and parse everything in the "project" for you, and it is doing that over a slow connection (ftp, sftp, ssh, etc.).

If you are using dreamweaver, check out this [KB Article](http://helpx.adobe.com/dreamweaver/kb/hang-opening-document-dreamweaver-cs5.html) and this [Google Search](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=dreamweaver%20slow%20ftp&oq=&gs_l=&pbx=1&fp=bfd4e169a20676d6&ion=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44442042,d.dmQ&biw=1615&bih=823).

Ultimately, you are going to have some performance hit, but you should be able to configure your IDE to minimize that. You can also always drop back to using something like FileZilla or WinSCP plus your favorite editor ... perhaps [Sublime Text with Remote Access](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp).

Comment: Thank's I'll try out the Dreamweaver stuff

Answer (score 0):

Trying to do dev over remote file system access is painfully slow. A few options:

- Use Remote Desktop (RDP) to connect into your machine and do local dev.
- You can always go the skydrive / google drive / dropbox route that syncs your dev files to your home computer so you can have local copies on both.
- Don't discount source control (though with that you can only make updates to what was checked in, so if you left the office without a checkin, you won't be able to do anything about it from home).